# Error in rendering of superscripts and subscripts

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown

In my answer [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/73361/20478), I use superscript and subscript for a footnote, but they appear at the same level as each other and as the regular text.

In the past, I've used the same bit of HTML on [rpg.se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), and they work as expected. I poked around a bit and couldn't find a specific post.

It appears that there is an error in the style sheet used over here.

Comment: Can you give working example from RPG

Comment: Meta SE - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296134/sup-superscript-html-tag-has-ceased-to-work-correctly

Comment: @Paulie_D Looks like it's not just my eyes or just this site.

Comment: Yep. Seems to be network wide.

Answer (score 2):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296182/288417 says [status-completed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), and it is. Yay.